# cannot access cloud9 IDE anymore on beaglebone black

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

Everything worked fine before. Once I powered on Beaglebone and could not access 192.168.7.2:3000 which is cloud9 IDE. I cannot also go to 192.168.7.2 as it is said on Getting started page for beaglebone. I can still shh to it and log in though.  Usually this problem goes with inability to ssh to it or absence of /var/lib/cloud9 directory but I can ssh and all the files in the directory are there. What would you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 0):

have you seen your C9 Ide state? Try this 3 following commands:

- root@beaglebone:~# systemctl enable bonescript.socket
- root@beaglebone:~# systemctl enable cloud9.socket
- root@beaglebone:~# systemctl enable bonescript-autorun.service